# Is this server setup efficent?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, isp

I have a web server at home. My IP address changes very often. My domain registrar is GoDaddy, so DynDNS does not work because GoDaddy only allows IP addresses for the A DNS Record. I can set a CNAME for www.mydomain.com that points to mydomain.dyndns.org, but I can't set an A Record.

The only solution that I can come up with is to buy a web hosting service and "proxy" the traffic to my IP. I'd redirect all traffic from example.com/* to index.php (or a script using another language) using .htaccess. Then I'd use index.php to fetch the content from my server at home.

Are there better ways to implement this?

Comment: Solution to what? You forgot to state what the problem is. What's wrong with making `www.mydomain.com` a CNAME for your dyndns name?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your registrar is GoDaddy doesn't mean you have to use GoDaddy's **nameservers**.

You can host your domain with any DNS hosting provider, just in registrar control panel you change  **nameservers** from godaddy's to those of your DNS hosting, like Dyn or whatever you like ([the biased list](http://talkdns.info/list) may be helpful).

Answer (score 1):

A records are IPv4 **a**ddresses, that's where the A comes from. You should set up a CNAME record.